# conda activate env "No such file or directory"

Tags: python-3.x, conda, anaconda3

Whenever I activate my second conda environment called `aiida`, I get an annoying message saying `env: 'aiida': No such file or directory`. Apart from this message, everything works correctly. Any ideas what could be causing this? The following picture illustrates the problem and shows the conda version and environment info. I tried reinstalling anaconda and recreating the environment but the problem persisted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after I posted this question, I realized the problem. Very embarrassing!

I had a malformed script in the `$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d` folder. All scripts in there are always called when the corresponding environment is activated.